# New depth of water in a cylindrical tank

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, newton-raphson

A cylindrical tank has a diameter of $60 cm$  and a height of $100 cm$.  It is filled with water to a depth of $10 cm$, then tilted by an angle $\theta = 30^\circ$.  What will be the new depth of water?  i.e. how high above the ground is the water surface in the tilted tank?

**My Approach:**

By taking horizontal slices of the water volume in the tilted tank, and integrating them to find the volume as a function of a set value $h$, and then iterating through Newton's iteration, I found that $h = 23.18cm$

Is there is a simpler or more direct way to solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Instead of taking horizontal slices, why don't you take slices parallel to the cylinder axis. They all will be rectangles, right?

Comment: That's also possible.  I would be interesting to see if you or others find the same depth value that I obtained.

Comment: I found the same result using slices parallel to the axis.

Comment: Another confirmation: with a $30$ deg tilt in the positive $y$ direction, the water level becomes parallel to the plane $y=\sqrt3\,z$. Solve for $k$ (which I find to be around $9.45$) such that the planes $z=\dfrac y{\sqrt3}+k$ and $z=0$, and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=30^2$ form the boundary of an [ungula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungula) with the same volume of water. Then the water level is the shortest distance from the plane to the point $(0,30,0)$, [same as your result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=distance+from+plane+z%3Dy%2Fsqrt%283%29%2B9.45+to+point+%280%2C30%2C0%29)